# Domain controller DNS issues

Tags: dns, windows-domain

Hi I'm trying to add a computer to a domain and keep getting this error DNS name does not exist.

- it's a brand new computer
- I've already added a couple of computers without getting this error, so I know it's not a server side issue
- I've already tried resetting adapter settings, adding DNS suffix, and manually add DNS server, nothing worked so far

Please answer if you have any ideas any help is greatly appreciated thanks

update

I ran a `nltest` and got the following error `ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN`

Comment: You should be able to go to a command prompt and `ping <domain name>`. If it can’t resolve the domain name then there is a problem with DNS. `nslookup` is another tool to work with. Double check your DNS server IP is correct and that you can reach the server. For further help you need to provide further details. Output of `ipconfig /all` information about your server IP, etc. you should be able to ping the domain by name and the domain controller and DNS server by IP.

Comment: @Appleoddity ping returns a response so does nslookup, I think there is a webserver on the same server as the domain controller, so it only gives me an error when trying to access the ac dc

Comment: are you using a FQDN or a shortname when attempting to join the domain? are you prompted to login with a domain admins credentials?

Comment: @FrankThomas I think a short name, I'm putting in domain.com

Comment: try just 'domain'. surprisingly I've seen that work. are you prompted for domain credentials?

Comment: When you ping `domain.com` does it return the IP address of the domain controller and are there successful replies?

Comment: @Appleoddity yes but I think it's the webserver replying

Comment: @FrankThomas no I get a DNS error not a dc error

Comment: That’s fine if there are more than one service on the same server. The important thing is that domain.com resolves to the IP address of the active directory domain controller and that the DNS server IP configured on the workstation is that of an active directory integrated DNS server (typically the same IP as the domain controller). If other workstations can join then all the DNS records themselves should be correct and not needed to be checked. It’s a matter of making sure the workstation can find them.

Comment: @Appleoddity so it all comes down to a local client issue, any pointers?

Comment: is that computer you try to add by any chance a Windows Home Version? Those you are not able to add to a WIndows AD domain.

Comment: @Zina no it's a windows pro

Comment: ok. DNS seems to be the issue. would you check the `ipconfig \all` output and confirm that DNS server(s) listed are your domain DNS servers and that you get a correct reply when querying for the domain name against all listed DNS servers from the ipconfig output on that workstation you want to add. if there is any public DNS listed - remove it an retry the domain join.

Comment: @Zina I tried adding the local DNS server without removing the default, maybe that's the issue? I'll try it when I get the chance and keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: if the default is not from your domain then that might be the issue. we will wait for your update.